# Polar equation for an ellipse that is not centred at the origin

Tags: conic-sections

Wikipedia says the polar form of an ellipse centred at the origin is 
[image]

What if the ellipse is not centred at the origin? Like its centred at (3, 4)?

Answer (score 1):

If one of the foci is at the origin, then the polar equation for the ellipse is $$r(\theta) = \frac{\ell}{1 + \epsilon \cos (\theta - \theta_0)},$$ where $\ell$ is the *semi-latus rectum* (for the ellipse you give, this is $\frac{b^2}{a}$), $\epsilon$ is the eccentricity, and $\theta_0$ is a reference angle (for the ellipse you give, this is $0$). (In fact this formula works for other conic sections just as well.)

If the origin is inside or on the ellipse but not at a focus, the formula is generally unpleasantly complicated.

If the origin is outside the ellipse, then the ellipse is not the graph of any (continuous) polar function (with period $2 \pi$), as some rays from the origin intersect the ellipse more than once.